# Find details when an event happens more than once on a given day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table that stores customer's transactions. The table contains a transaction id as its primary key, customer number, a transaction date and an item id.

I need to know when any customer has purchased more than just 1 distinct item id on a given day.

So in the table below, I would wanting to get all records back for just customer BBB as they have 2 different item ids on the same day. All of AAA's are the same itemid and CCCs were across 2 different days.

```
+---------+------------+------------+--------+
| TransId | CustomerId |    Date    | ItemId |
+---------+------------+------------+--------+
|       1 | AAA        | 24/11/2020 |     11 |
|       2 | AAA        | 24/11/2020 |     11 |
|       3 | AAA        | 24/11/2020 |     11 |
|       4 | BBB        | 23/11/2020 |     12 |
|       5 | BBB        | 23/11/2020 |     11 |
|       6 | CCC        | 23/11/2020 |     11 |
|       7 | CCC        | 24/11/2020 |     11 |
+---------+------------+------------+--------+
```

I have tried this but it seems to return all rows ...

```
select customerid, date, itemid
from transactions
group by customerid, date, itemid
having count(itemid) > 1
```

Comment: Remove item from the grouping.

Comment: I am assuming you want itemid to be part of the results, right?

Answer (score 1):

use `count(distinct itemid)` and remove `the item field` from the `group by clause`

```
Select customerid, date from transactions 
group by customerid, date
having count(distinct itemid) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  CUSTOMERID,DATE ORDER BY TEMID) AS RUN
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMERID,DATE,TEMID 
from transactions) a)
SELECT B.CustomerId,B.Date,B.temId FROM CTE B inner join (
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMERid,DATE FROM CTE WHERE RUN > 1)C
ON B.CustomerId=C.CustomerId AND B.Date = C.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want itemid to be part of the results, this should work:

```
SELECT t.CustomerId, t.ItemId, t.Date
FROM(
     SELECT CustomerId, ItemId, COUNT(itemid) AS Trans
     FROM transactions
     GROUP BY CustomerId, ItemId
) AS a
JOIN transactions t
    ON t.CustomerId = a.CustomerId
    AND t.ItemId <> a.ItemId
```